# Java how to send active connection to other class

Tags: java, multithreading, server, connection, client

I want to send active connection to other class and i dont know if can i do that.

I have method and constructor on client side

```
 public ChatClient(String serverName, int serverPort) {
    this.serverName = serverName;
    this.serverPort = serverPort;
}

public boolean connect() {
    try {
        this.socket = new Socket(serverName, serverPort);
        System.out.println("Client port: " + socket.getLocalPort());
        this.serverOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        this.serverIn = socket.getInputStream();
        this.bufferedIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverIn));
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Calling it here in my another class

```
        public LoginUserWindow(){
        JFrame f= new JFrame("Panel Example");

        this.client = new ChatClient("localhost", 2137);
        client.connect();
       }
```

Now i have connection to my server and i want to call another class with this same connection

```
 loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

           AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass(here must be active connection i think);
   }



 });
```

Someone know how should i do it or how to do it better?

Comment: Just save it as an attribute?

Comment: can you give example ?

Answer (score 0):

> Now i have connection to my server and i want to call another class with this same connection

For another class to handle a particular connection on the server, that class needs to be passed in all of the fields that it needs to do that job.  Typically, the server calls `serverSocket.accept()` which returns a `Socket` that then can be passed into the class which will be handling the connection.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
while (running) {
   Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
   threadPool.submit(new ClientHandler(socket));
}
// stop the thread pool – you can do shutdownNow() to interrupt the current clients
threadPool.shutdown();
// wait for all of the existing clients to finish
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Connections are accepted on the server which adds them to a thread-pool to be run in parallel.  `ClientHandler` should implement `Runnable`.  Inside the `ClientHandler` it should do all of the operations to service that particular connection.

The server will continue to accept connections on the socket until the `running` flag is set to false or the `serverSocket` is closed or something.

Hope something here helps.